# Make UI button appear when all of my objects have been collected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

It's a small part of my project that I need to do and I'm not sure how to approach it.

I have these objects that should be able to walk into, and once they've collected all 5 of them, the UI button on the grey box in the top left corner of their screen appears. I have been spending ages trying to figure it out but I can't.

I have the coding experience of an absolute beginner. This is literally my first coding experience.

Code attempted to use:

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class destroyobject : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject button;
        public int collectable = 5;


        void Start()
        {
            button.SetActive(false);
         }

        void OnTriggerEnter(Collider obj)
        {
            collectable = -1;            
             if (collectable <= 0)
            button.SetActive(true);

          Destroy (obj.gameObject);
       }
    }
```

Comment: thats quite cruel. but its my first time posting so maybe this is normal. its a small part of my project. I already have the full scene done, you can walk into the objects and they are deleted, its just that my button immediately appears after collecting the first pill and I dont know why. im going to add the code I attempted to use into the question (might not fit in the comment is all) im not quite sure which object to put the script on..

Comment: It is very common. This site is doesn't exists so that we can do YOUR work for you - but help you if you enter a deadend. Consult this link on [how to ask a  question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it just seem un-neededly hostile is all. scares me a bit, im not very smart and just needed a leg up so to speak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

First make `colelctable` a `static` variable. So it stands same for all the 5 collider objects which have your script:

```
public static int collectable = 5;
```

then change your `OnTriggerEnter` like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider obj) 
{
    collectable --;
    if (collectable <= 0)
        button.SetActive(true);

    Destroy(obj.gameObject);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you this does help. but now the problem is it then deletes all doors and other objects it can collide with indiscriminately and counts them towards minusing from the collectable value....

Comment: Please accept the answer. And that is another question for another time.

Comment: considering your the only person whose even been close to nice to me so far, I think I shall. but I think im gonna refrain from asking questions here again XD I dont have a deathwish

Answer (score 0):

Your tokens needs a collider on them and your Character will need either a RigidBody or a CharacterController. Then you can use a [OnCollisionEnter()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.OnCollisionEnter.html) to see if they are in contact and then destroy them.

You can then put a tag on the tokens [FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) will return an array of GameObjects with the provided tag. Then check if that Array is empty. If it is well activate your button.

I wont do your whole assignement, but I think this is enough to get you started. Look in the Unity Documentation about the Methods I mentionned.